# Can a sequence cover all the irrational numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, irrational-numbers

Is there any sequence that covers all the irrational numbers?
Like $\forall x \in I$, $\exists n\in \mathbb{N}$  s.t. $a_n = x$.

I think the answer is not, but I need help to prove this, if you have some argument please comment on it.

Comment: The set of irrational numbers is uncountable, therefore it is not possible.

Comment: [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument)